# how can I pass parametrs from file.haml with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a haml file with ruby on rails. This is my code:

```
%p.form_row.actions
  = submit_tag
```

I want to send parameters in submit. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you read through this? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: I tried few times but didnt succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your form structured like?

For example:

```
= form_tag(search_path, :method => "get") do
  = label_tag(:q, "Search for:")
  = text_field_tag(:q)
  = submit_tag("Search")
```

That initiates a GET request to the `search_path` route (which is created in the `routes.rb` file) and passes in a parameter called `:q` to the controller action

So if you had this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
match :search, :to => 'my_controller#search', :via => [:get]
```

Then your controller action `MyController#search` would look like

```
def search
  # this is the parameter passed in from the form
  query_string = params[:q]

  # now do something with the parameter...
end
```